# C# char returns emoji or nothing

Tags: c#, minesweeper

I'm trying to learn c# and trying to make simple minesweeper game on console. When i am returning int to char it returns '' or an emoji when it should return me 0-3. I know that my code is not clean i am still learning just the basics.

```
public char howManyMinesHaveBeenPut(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
        {
            short howMany = 0;

            if(canPlayerPut(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate - 1) && isMine(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate - 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 1");
            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate, yCoordinate - 1) && isMine(xCoordinate, yCoordinate - 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 2");

            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate - 1) && isMine(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate - 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 3");

            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate) && isMine(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 4");

            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate) && isMine(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 5");

            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate + 1) && isMine(xCoordinate - 1, yCoordinate + 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 6");

            }

            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate, yCoordinate + 1) && isMine(xCoordinate, yCoordinate + 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 7");

            }
            if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate + 1) && isMine(xCoordinate + 1, yCoordinate + 1))
            {
                howMany++;
                Console.WriteLine("Mina 8");

            }

            return Convert.ToChar(howMany);
        }
```

I've tried (char), convert to char, changing from int to short.

here is the link for full code:
https://github.com/Thuthutka/minesweeper/blob/main/Program.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerical values that represent the Arabic digits are `48` (`'0'`) to `57` (`'9'`). You're using the values from `0` to `3` which represent control characters. You need add `'0'` or `48` to your values to get the correct character returned.

```
return Convert.ToChar(howMany + '0');
```

---

You might want to try this implementation:

```
public char howManyMinesHaveBeenPut(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate)
{
    int howMany = 0;
    int mine = 0;

    for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
        {
            mine++;
            if (x != 0 && y != 0)
            {
                if (canPlayerPut(xCoordinate + x, yCoordinate + y) && isMine(xCoordinate + x, yCoordinate + y))
                {
                    howMany++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Mina {mine}");
                }
            }
        }
    
    return Convert.ToChar(howMany + '0'); 
}
```

---

Also, please considering using the standard C# naming convention for methods - Pascal, not camal, case.

Answer (score -2):

if you want a character that represents the single digit. Ie "1" for 1 you need

```
 howMany.ToString()[0]
```

ie - convert to a string and take the first character